# junit hibernate netbeans: CurrentSessionContext

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, junit

I'm trying to test my hibernate project with junit tests and I keep on getting `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!`

I can manually run the hibernate requests and they work fine (i.e. I have included `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>` which seems the be the regular cause of the aforementioned exception).

It seems as if the junit test does not 'pick up' the hibernate.cfg.xml file because it's lying in the default Netbeans `Test Packages` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the hibernate.xml.cfg file is in the same directory as the junit test class. By default it will look for the file in the same directory it I executed in, unless the path is specified in the sessionfactory object when created.

Update: Also make sure that you initialize the sessionFactory. When you get a new session, it is possible that you've never initialized the factory, since your unit test could be bypassing the code that generally initializes it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that before, unfortunately it does not make a difference.

Comment: I've recently had a similar problem. When including a library that has a hibernate.cfg.xml file inside it, in the test directory, my junit test did not want to create the hibernate sessionFactory. After removing the hibernate config file from all libraries that I included, it managed to find the correct config file, and run the junit test. 
I hope this helps.